# Linux: Use VNC to create a second Screen

Tags: vnc, xorg

I'm planning to use my 7" Android tablet as second screen via VNC.

Sharing my main screen works fine with x11vnc, but that is not what I want.

So I created a second screen using the xorg86-video-dummy driver and share this screen with `x11vnc -display :1` which works but I don't get it managed to use xrandr "extending" this screen with the main screen... .

What am I doing wrong or is there a better solution? The driver for the main screen is the cs nvidia one.

Comment: Can you try to clear up a few ambiguities for me? Where are you creating this second screen? I don't understand what you mean by "which works but I don't get it ma[n]aged to use xrandr 'extending' this screen with main screen" either. If you could clarify your question, I think you'd have a better chance at getting a good response.

Comment: > but I don't get it mamaged to use xrandr "extending" this screen What did you try? What happenned when you tried it? What does xrandr --auto show?

Comment: `user@Thinkpad-T61>xrandr --screen 1
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 1: minimum 320 x 240, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.0     56.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        60.0     56.0  
   320x240        60.0`

Comment: `caco@Thinkpad-T61>xrandr --screen 0
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 175, current 1440 x 900, maximum 1440 x 900
default connected 1440x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1440x900       50.0*    51.0     52.0  
   1024x768       53.0     54.0     55.0     56.0     57.0  
...`

Comment: But i can't set something like "xrandr --output VGA-0 --left-of LVDS" or in my case somethig like this "xrandr --output --Screen-1 --left-of -Screen-0"(If something is possible with Xrandr...)

Comment: Okey, here is the important part of my second xorg.conf:
`
Section "ServerLayout" 
    Identifier     "Layout" 
    Screen      0  "ScreenVNC" 0 0 
EndSection

Section "Monitor"...
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "ScreenVNC"
    Device         "DeviceVNC"
    Monitor        "MonitorVNC"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes     "800x480" 
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "DeviceVNC"
    Driver         "dummy"
EndSection
`

I can share this Screen with x11vnc but I want to use this screen...

Comment: As second screen by extendig it with xrandr ore something like this...

Comment: Your setup looks quite interesting. Can you provide your xorg.conf.dummy files? Thx, yanosz

Answer (score 4):

I think I have found a solution using xdmx instead of xrandr; I will try this on a virtual machine running two xservers (with dummy devices) plus xdmx as primary xserver.

My first try with two "dummy xservers":

```
Xorg :2 -config /etc/X11/xorg.conf.dummy & // my "real screen"
Xorg :3 -config /etc/X11/xorg.conf.dummy & // my "vnc screen"
Xdmx :4 +xinerama -display localhost:2 -display localhost:3 &
x11vnc -display :3 -noshm
```

Works, but now I have to tell slim to work with xserver number 4 and put this all together into a failsafe bash script.