# How to use 3 notebooks as multiple screens for my desktop on linux over network?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors

I like to use my 3 laptops as secondaries screens only, as multiple monitors, to use laptops as screens, and drag windows running on my desktop to the laptops. What the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You may try xdmx.  Basically it will allow you to use an old laptop as an extra monitor. Here are some links:
http://dmx.sourceforge.net/
and real life application
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOzRCBGDVaE

Second option  for You is Synergy
https://symless.com/synergy
for sure it shares one mouse and keyboard between multiple computers

Comment: Yes, this is what i trying, I'm following exactly that video instructions, but nothing happens, when i run these commands, i get nothing: https://superuser.com/questions/1301104/trying-to-run-startx-usr-bin-xdmx-xinerama-and-nothing-happens

Comment: Please take a look at this answer. Maybe you will get something out of it https://superuser.com/questions/395227/using-spare-pc-as-second-monitor

Answer (score -3):

What you're trying to do, with the little information you have provided, it's going to be difficult. With the description you have given it's likely that you expect the regular user experience and dragging a live application from one running system to another isn't easy.

A laptop can't be attached directly as a secondary display to your system. Each of those devices is independent and will need to run its own OS and probably some software to get you part of the experience you want.

On option would be synergy which just would allow you to freely move mouse and keyboard from one system to the other without requiring a hardware switch. As you're running Linux it might be possible to find some solution that's going to allow you to view a virtual screen or maybe even just the Window of an application on another machine. <strike>But it's unlikely that it will allow you to just drag applications from one machine to another. You will likely have some form of user experience break.</strike>

Comment: i see a lot of people doing that with vnc, maxivista, xinerama...... i cant replicate, trying and fail, but not impossible at al

Comment: The problem is that, with your description, you're trying to move a live application from one running system to another. Which isn't done easily. There might be some workarounds like having a virtual screen on your system that some remove viewer like VNC is viewing but the user experience is going to be different from the regular one. If you do have examples why did you not include them in your question?

Comment: i just need to run an app in my desktop and drag the window to the laptop (no need to move the proccess to laptop), need to move just the X part (the screen - the window to another X client or watherever). Can be any kind of virtual screen over network.

Comment: like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hibaFjxAQAg

Comment: @AugustoWill thanks for link but neither are those computers just used as displays, they are actually running, nor does it seem to be an easy solution. Regardless it's interesting to see that it is possible.